# How to access JSON property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble in accessing JSON property by key value.

This is my JSON and i would like to access `overSerializedItems` and `underSerializedItems` as string format but not able to display any data

```js
response = [{
    "storeId": "2011",
    "overSerializedItems": [{
        "overshipid": "8901260932784148868F"
      },
      {
        "overshipid": "8901260145723866348F"
      },
    ],
    "underSerializedItems": [],
  },
  {
    "storeId": "2011",
    "overSerializedItems": [],
    "underSerializedItems": [{
        "undershipid": "89"
      },
      {
        "undershipid": "81"
      },
    ],
  }
]
```

I am trying following approach but getting error 'Can not read property tostring() of undefined'

```
 for(const item of response) {
  const json = {
      'Store #': item.storeId,
      'Overshipment': item.overSerializedItems !== null ? 
       item.overSerializedItems.overshipid.toString() : [], //Here values i should get 8901260932784148868F,8901260145723866348F
       'Undershipment':item.underSerializedItems !== null ? 
       item.underSerializedItems.undershipid.toString() : [] // Here values i should get are 89,81 
     }  
}
```

Comment: There's no JSON in your question. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript (or TypeScript) source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: _What does the error say_?

Comment: `item.overSerializedItems` is an array, you can't access the `overshipid` property of it

Comment: Getting error can not read property tostring() of undefined

Comment: Yeah, you are getting that array, because you have to first access elements of the array in order to access `overshipid` of them

Answer (score 1):

You're using `!== null` to check whether `overSerializeItems` and/or `underSerializedItems` are absent from the response. That check will be false, because if they're absent, you get `undefined`, not `null`, when you try to access them on the object.

In both of those cases, since they're either absent or objects, just use an `item.overSerializedItems ?` guard:

```
for (const item of response) {
  const obj = { // not JSON
    'Store #': item.storeId,
    'Overshipment': item.overSerializedItems ?
      item.overSerializedItems : [],
    'Undershipment': item.underSerializedItems ?
      item.underSerializedItems : []
  }
  console.log(obj);
}
```

or if you're supply a default `[]` if the array isn't present, use `||`:

```
for (const item of response) {
  const obj = { // not JSON
    'Store #': item.storeId,
    'Overshipment': item.overSerializedItems || [],
    'Undershipment': item.underSerializedItems || []
  }
  console.log(obj);
}
```

Also note that there's no point to `.toString()` on `overshipid` and `undershipid`; they're *already* strings. But I've removed that anyway, since you were trying to use `.overshipid` and `.undershipid` on **arrays**; they don't exist as properties on the arrays, they exist as properties of the objects *within* the arrays. (Removing them also makes the `[]` default there make more sense.)

Live Example:

```js
const response = [{
    "storeId": "2011",
    "overSerializedItems": [{
        "overshipid": "8901260932784148868F"
      },
      {
        "overshipid": "8901260145723866348F"
      },
    ],
    "underSerializedItems": [],
  },
  {
    "storeId": "2011",
    "overSerializedItems": [],
    "underSerializedItems": [{
        "undershipid": "89"
      },
      {
        "undershipid": "81"
      },
    ],
  }
];

for (const item of response) {
  const obj = { // not JSON
    'Store #': item.storeId,
    'Overshipment': item.overSerializedItems || [],
    'Undershipment': item.underSerializedItems || []
  }
  console.log(obj);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response i tried this approach but i am getting [object object] how to display the undershipid and overshipid values?

Comment: @Uidev123 - (The above won't show you `[object Object]` on a standard console.) You have to do something with the array they're in. What that is will depend on what you want to do.